# How do I disconnect my Bluemix Git Repo from my Bluemix App?

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, devops

I have a Liberty Application in Bluemix that is connected to a Bluemix Git repository.  I would like to disconnect the 2 from each other with out removing or effecting either one.  I have already removed the Build and Deploy steps but the "Git URL" still shows up indicating some connection between the 2.  I have already tried to change the settings of the Repository options page by unchecking the "Make this a Bluemix Project", but it fails and don't allow me to do it.

Is there a way to do this without deleting and recreating either one of them?

Comment: If you delete the bluemix git repository, then the git URL disappears from your bluemix app. I realise this is exactly what you don't want to do, but I haven't found another way to remove the link.

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkout the code locally

   git clone #gitRepoUrl
2. See the remote repo on this project

   git remote -v
3. Remove the appropriate repo (in this case, origin)

   git remote rm origin
4. Push to bluemix

   cf push